# How can I set up the environment in WSL before CLion invokes CMake

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion

I use [environment modules](https://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to dynamically set up my development environment in WSL / ubuntu, which means that I try to only have a very minimum set of tools installed in my /usr/bin directory with the rest being loaded at runtime.

This does, however, then also mean that I have to load the modules before I do any compilation (for example "module load CMake GCC"). Is there an option in CLion that lets me pass commands to be executed in WSL before CMake is invoked? Or is there a way to let CLion connect to an existent WSL session which has been pre-configured?

Comment: I took the pragmatic approach, i.e. removed windows and installed ubuntu, as far as I am concerned, at least for me this is an acceptable workaround ...